# How to merge two cell in google sheet using PHP API?

Tags: php, google-sheets

How to merge two cell in google sheet using google spreadsheet api (PHP) ?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#mergecellsrequest

Answer (score 0):

For someone looking for solution to do merging using google spreadsheet API in PHP, then you can follow as below, but please note for this code to run you must be using Google Sheet API PHP SDK. Also you must declare these classes used in this code in your class or php file at the top using `use` keyword.

```
####### Set the Grid Range in sheet ########
$rangeinst = new Google_Service_Sheets_GridRange();
$rangeinst->setSheetId($setSheetId); //set your sheet id here
$rangeinst->setStartRowIndex(0); //start row
$rangeinst->setEndRowIndex(2); //end row
$rangeinst->setStartColumnIndex(0); //start column
$rangeinst->setEndColumnIndex(4); //end column

########## Set Grid range object in merging #########
$merge = new Google_Service_Sheets_MergeCellsRequest();
$merge->setMergeType('MERGE_COLUMNS'); //Can be MERGE_ROWS or MERGE_ALL for more you can check https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange
$merge->setRange($rangeinst);

//update the sheet with merge request object                
$requestMergeBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request();
$requestMergeBody->setMergeCells($merge);
$mergerequestBatchBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
$mergerequestBatchBody->setRequests($requestMergeBody);
$service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $mergerequestBatchBody);     //$spreadsheetId is different than sheet id (a sheet index) so don't confuse with these two terms,
//spreadsheetId will be your whole spreadsheet unique Id that you can found in your share url of spreadsheet and will look something like this 1Mbd5MsTixm5SE0HHl0-yVqj_4ENwijSdNm5OAiG4pN0
```